# Initiating schema in PostgreSQL RDS?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, node-postgres

I'm trying to build an app using Node/Express and RDS PostgreSQL on the back-end to get some more experience with these two technologies. More specifically, I'm looking to build this using the node-postgres package and without the aid of an ORM. I currently have a .sql file in my app that contains the desired schema.

What would be considered "best practice" when implementing a schema for the first time? For example, is it considered better to import a schema via the command line, use something like pgAdmin, or throw a bunch of "CREATE TABLEs" into queries through node-postgres?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: There is no best practice in this, you are free to do as you like.

Comment: I would suggest you separate structure and content manipulation - content namaged by node.js app, and structure by sql scripts with psql or flyway or sqitch or some other meant way

Comment: @VaoTsun That's helpful, thank you!